# How is smooth animation accomplished?

Tags: transformations, animation

How are objects moved smoothly from point A to point B given  matrix transformations that describe next position?

Comment: [Skeletal Animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_animation)

Comment: I assume the question is really how are transformation matrices interpolated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093455/3d-geometry-how-to-interpolate-a-matrix

Comment: Or have a look at screw theory.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Graphics SE! I think there's a good and interesting question there, but currently it's not clear what exactly is being asked. Please consider editing some more detail into your question and also show what you've tried/found out yourself.